# servlet problem while passing values of float from one servlet to other servlet

Tags: java, servlets, jsp-tags, servletconfig

```
<!-- language: java-->
    package bhatti;
    public class find extends HttpServlet {

     @Override
     protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     throws ServletException, IOException {

      response.setContentType("text/html;");
      PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

      out.println("<html><body>");
      out.println("<feildset>");
      out.println("<form action='display' method='get'>");
      out.println("<tr>");
      out.println("<td>ID :</td><td> <input type='text' name='id' style='width=70px;'></td><tr><br>");
      out.println("<tr><td>Uints: </tr><tr><input type='text' name='uints' style='width=70px;' ></td></tr><br>");
      out.println("<tr><td><input type='submit' value='submit' ></td></tr><br>");
      out.println("</form>");
      out.println("</feildset>");
      out.println("</body></html>");

      int i = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
      int u = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("uints"));

      float bill;

      bill = (float)(u * (1.5));

      float s;

      s = (float)(bill * 0.05);

      float totalbill;

      totalbill = bill - s;

      RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("display.java");
      requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);

      request.setAttribute("id", i);
      request.setAttribute("uints", u);
      request.setAttribute("totalbill", totalbill);

     }
    }
```

> ```
> second servlet
> ```

```
package bhatti;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

public class display extends HttpServlet {

 @Override
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 throws ServletException, IOException {

  response.setContentType("text/html;");
  PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

  int i = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));

  int u = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("uints"));

  float tb = Float.parseFloat(request.getParameter("totalbill"));

  out.println("<p>ID: " + i + "  </p><br>");
  out.println("<p>Uints: " + u + "</p><br>");
  out.println("<p>Subsidy: " + "  5%" + "</p><br>");
  out.println("<h1>Total Bill:" + tb + "</h1><br>");

 }

}
```

> ## float value is not sending to the other servlet
>
> ## error is  HTTP Status 500 -
>
> type Exception report
>
> message
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException
>     sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1838)
>     sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseFloat(FloatingDecimal.java:122)
>     java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:451)
>     bhatti.display.doGet(display.java:26)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
>
> note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache
>   Tomcat/8.0.27 logs.

Comment: Set a breakpoint and check the value. Is it null? Think why it is null.

Comment: sir i am new in java kindly help me out from this problem . and i try that now error 404 occurs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting attribute in one servlet, and trying to getParameter in another servlet.

setAttribute value can not be obtained by getParameter but
**setAttribute value can only be obtained by getAttribute**

So use getAttribute from request as

```
request.getAttribute ("totalBill") ;
```

In your case `request.getParameter("totalBill")` Is NULL and `Float.parseFloat(null)` will through `NullPointerException` and hence you got HttpResponse status 500 i.e, Internl Server Error.

Comment: after that now having HTTP Status 404 - error

Comment: Integer.parseInt(null)  leads to NullPointerException and hence 500 error.

Comment: Is that answers your question?

Comment: no Sir i am try to find bill of electricity. Problem is that in one servlet i have to calculate the  bill and in other servlet will the output of the bill

Comment: i try also using getAttribute  but error is not gone

Comment: Print request.getAttrinute("totalBill")  and check what you will see. And also reply here shart is the exception.

Comment: HTTP Status 404 - Not Found
type Status report
messageNot Found
descriptionThe requested resource is not available.

Comment: Once you print,   request.getAttrinute("totalBill") What you got? 500 error gone right?